# unable to launch application in separate X server

Tags: x-server

I am using Manjaro Xfce 0.8.8 right now.
I want to launch application in separate X server so I typed in the following command to launch Chromium for example:

```
xinit /usr/bin/chromium -- :1
```

but I get this error:

```
Fatal server error:
Cannot move old log file "/var/log/Xorg.1.log" to "/var/log/Xorg.1.log.old"


Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
```

Comment: Check this link. http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-608489-view-previous.html?sid=decf7dd90db8b8a16ef563dc32e9fdd1 It seems similar to your issue. Though, it is gentoo, the answers mentioned is worth a try.

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't apply to my problem, I don't have nosuid option in fstab.

Answer (score 0):

If there's some permission problem and you can't start a *real* X server, you can always try to run an X server within your running X server:

- The oldest one is probably [Xnest](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/Xnest.1.html)
- A more advanced one is [Xephyr](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/Xephyr/), supporting various modern X extensions